# sklearn CountVectorizer.transform() returns different results with the same input

Tags: python, scikit-learn, countvectorizer

Im currently implementing TFIDF in python and I got pretty puzzling results when testing my cosine distance function. It looks like this:

```
    def cosSim(self, doc1,doc2):
        docList = [doc1, doc2]
        count_vector = self.cv.transform(docList)
        tf_idf_vector = self.tfidfTrans.transform(count_vector)
        cos_sim = cosine_similarity(tf_idf_vector)
        return cos_sim[0][1]
```

The problem is that that self.cv.transform(docList) will return different results, sometimes it looks like this

```
  (0, 720)  1
  (0, 824)  1
  (0, 864)  1
  (0, 1456) 1
  (0, 1762) 1
  (0, 1890) 1
  (0, 2406) 1
  (0, 2593) 1
  (0, 3244) 1
  (0, 4258) 1
  (0, 4414) 1
  (1, 969)  1
  (1, 2416) 1
  (1, 2661) 1
  (1, 4075) 1
  (1, 4258) 1

and sometimes (wrong) like this
  (0, 720)  1
  (0, 824)  1
  (0, 864)  1
  (0, 1456) 1
  (0, 1762) 1
  (0, 1890) 1
  (0, 2406) 1
  (0, 2593) 1
  (0, 3244) 1
  (0, 4258) 1
  (0, 4414) 1
```

So it seems to be "eating" the 2nd document. This isnt even consistent between program executions, calling the function in a loop while return both results seemingly at random. Any idea whats causing this?

Edit:
Im building my model like this:

```
    def build_tfidf(self, docList):
        self.cv = CountVectorizer(stop_words=self.stop_words, strip_accents='ascii', tokenizer=tokenize)
        word_count_vector = self.cv.fit_transform(docList)
        self.tfidfTrans = TfidfTransformer(use_idf=True)
        self.tfidfTrans.fit(word_count_vector)
        self.vocab = self.cv.get_feature_names()
```

I called the function like and still get the weird results:

```
tfidf = TFIDF()
tfidf.build_tfidf(data)
doc1 = "However, a few cooperative transaction models have been proposed to facilitate collaboration, usually while maintaining some guarantees of consistency."
doc2 = "Transaction Management in Multidatabase Systems Databases."
for i in range(0,10):
    sim = tfidf.cosSim(doc1, doc2)
    print(sim)
```

Edit2: After some tinkering I found a fix but not a solution: If I dont pass the CountVectorizer() a tokenizer I starts working. Problem is I need that tokenizer and that still doesnt explain why it doesnt work with it. Here is the tokenize code just in case although it is probably unrelated:

```
def tokenize(doc):
    tokens = regex_tokenize(doc)
    stemmed = porter_stem(tokens)
    return stemmed

def regex_tokenize(doc, reg=u'(?u)\\b\\w\\w+\\b'):
    words = []
    token_pattern = re.compile(reg)
    lan = ""
    try:
        lan = detect(doc)
    except :
        pass
    if lan == "en":
        words = token_pattern.findall(doc)
    return words

def porter_stem(doc):
    porter_stemmer = PorterStemmer()
    stemmed_words = []
    for word in doc:
        match = re.match("[0-9]+", word)
        if match is None: #& match.group() != word:
            stemmed_words.append(porter_stemmer.stem(word))
    return stemmed_words
```

In my cosSim function, also tried splitting up

```
count_vector = cv.transform([doc1, doc2])
```

into

```
count_vector1 = cv.transform([doc1])
count_vector2 = cv.transform([doc2])
print(f"vec1: {count_vector1}")
print(f"vec2: {count_vector2}")
```

but even after that it sometimes *still* doesnt calculate the 2nd vector:

```
vec1:   (0, 266)    1
  (0, 294)  1
  (0, 527)  1
  (0, 603)  1
  (0, 743)  2
  (0, 1022) 1
vec2:   (0, 266)    1
  (0, 656)  1
  (0, 709)  1
  (0, 1068) 1
  (0, 1122) 1
0.09454412899652256


vec1:   (0, 266)    1
  (0, 294)  1
  (0, 527)  1
  (0, 603)  1
  (0, 743)  2
  (0, 1022) 1
vec2:
```

Comment: The most likely case here is that the input are not actually the same due to a bug in the code that is calling `cosSim()`.  Please post that code.

Comment: added the code to question

Answer (score 0):

So turns out the problem actually *was* the tokenizer. The langdetect module I was using is appearetnly non-deterministic, so I would get different results on the same piece of text.